# Query Join Question

Tags: sql, join

Why does this query return from both tables instead of only from OVPM?

```
SELECT *
from OVPM M1
JOIN VPM2 M2 ON M2.DocNum = M1.DocNum
AND Canceled = 'N'
WHERE M1.DocNum = '2292'
```

Answer (score 5):

Because you queried everything `*`. If you need the data only from `OVPM` - replace it with `M1.*`

Comment: even when I do M1.* I get the same results.